# I can't remove the action bar from my application

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I am trying to remove the Action Bar from my app, but it just won't leave. Here is what I have done:

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

`styles.xml` v21:

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And the app theme is set to No Action Bar.

I also am doing this in the `MainActivity.java` class:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

But that only removes it when I run the app. I would like it to be gone in the design panel.

How is that done?

Comment: Android Studio's design panel ?

Comment: What is the theme of your `MainActivity.java` in the manifest file? Have you set ` android:theme` for your the activity?

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` has "no action bar"... But `AppTheme.NoActionBar` doesn't extend that theme...

Comment: Have you tried `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` in the manifest?

Comment: Can you also add your manifest?

Answer (score 2):

> But that only removes it when I run the app. I would like it to be
>   gone in the design panel.

Simply, use a theme without `ActionBar` on Android Studio's Preview:

[image]

I said that because you said it's working after compiling the app and your question was about:

> I would like it to be gone in the **design panel**

Design panel!

---

But, this will only show you how to remove that `ActionBar` on Andorid Studio's Preview.

The thing is, it should be like this:

In `Manifest`:

```
<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

And if it is still there, You should check if there is a `Toolbar` in your `Layouts`

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `parent` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Similarly:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And don't forget to add theme declaration in `manifest` using:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Hope this would help!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `manifest.xml` on this line:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

delete `Apptheme`,  than typing Theme. with a dot (.) it will show you different options of theme layouts.
follow the pictures:

[image: pic1]

This will affect only the emulator. In order to see also the effect in the `activity_main.xml`, just go on that tab activity and press, form the preview window, the button no the top right corner "NoActionBar" as I show in follow picture, choose form the dialog box "manifest theme" and hit OK.
this will change the preview too!

[image: snapshot]

hope this will help ;)